# Change the text in a button with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small piece of VBA code that allows me to expand and collapse rows by clicking a button (by assigning the Macro to the button):

```
Sub Expand()
Range("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (Range("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden)
Range("9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (Range("9:9").EntireRow.Hidden)
End Sub
```

Currently, I have just manually typed in the text "EXPAND" onto the button, however I would like the text top dynamically change to say "COLLAPSE" when the rows are visible and "EXPAND" when the rows are hidden.

Thank you.

Comment: `button.caption=iif(Range("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden,"Expand","Collapse")`

Comment: Or if created as a shape - `Shapes("<name of shape>").DrawingObject.Caption = IIF...`

Comment: This hasn't worked, I'm sure I'm missing something. I get the error "424": Object required. I have copied the ```button.caption``` code exactly. Am I to call the button name, if so where?

Comment: You could use `Range("4:4,9:9")` btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Form Controls Button then assign this macro (in regular/standard module) to the button

Edited as suggested by @KekuSemau in the comments on the question

```
Sub Macro1()
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")
    If .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Expand" Then
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Collapse"
    ActiveSheet.Range("4:4,9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Expand"
    ActiveSheet.Range("4:4,9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

If you are using ActiveX Controls Command Button then Paste this macro in the relevant sheet VBA module. Make sure the button name is correct.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If CommandButton1.Caption = "Expand" Then
    CommandButton1.Caption = "Collapse"
    ActiveSheet.Range("4:4,9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    CommandButton1.Caption = "Expand"
    ActiveSheet.Range("4:4,9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]